# How to generate a new bower.json

Tags: bower

I have a project where I have checked in my bower_components folder into github a loooong time ago.  The project works with when I run my build script by compiling many files in my bower_components folder into base.js.

The problem is, I unfortunately have not been properly installing bower packages.  Instead of typing "bower install package-name --save" I have just been adding packages via "bower install package-name".  Thus, my bower.json has not been updated properly.

Since my repo is HUUUGGE due to the checking in of the bower_components folder, I want to start a NEW repo without the bower_components folder.  Problem is, my project doesn't build properly unless I have all the files from my checked in bower_components folder.

**What I need done:**
I need a program that will go through all of the sub-folders in my bower_components folder and build a new bower.json file.

Answer (score 5):

enter on your project directory and type:  bower init

answer all of the prompted questions as you need to(ie: name, description, main, license, homepage..etc) and put Yes on this one:

set currently installed components as dependencies? Yes

it will create a bower.json with your actual installation packages.

Comment: This, followed by `bower prune` (Removes local extraneous packages) sounds good.

Answer (score 4):

First initialise the bower:
type this command

```
 bower init
```

bower.json file will be created.

Now you can add dependency to it.
You can install the package with following syntax:

```
bower install <package>
```

Example:

```
 bower install jquery-nice-select
```

You can add it to bower.json be adding --save next to it

```
bower install jquery-nice-select --save
```

Enjoy :)